# UITableViewCell with url connects to UIViewController with WebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, webview

So long story short, I have been struggling with this block of code all day I am using a **prepareForSegue** method. I have a random link the user types in and places in a tableView. Now the user can click on the cell in the tableView which connects to the link through another UIViewController with a WebView. The problem is that I can't get the algorithm that will display the website in the webView. I am also new to Objective-C.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showArticle"]) {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSString *string = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
```

This is from the tableView. Maybe I should use **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** Help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`! Otherwise, your TableViewController does not know that the user selected a cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.propertyToStoreTheString = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showArticle" sender:nil];
}
```

And in your `prepareForSegue`-method, you just have to use `[((MyViewController *)[segue destinationViewController]) setUrl:self.propertyToStoreTheString];`

Comment: Ok, I used the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method. but I still can't figure out **prepareForSegue** method. the `setUrl:self.propertyToStoreTheString` gets an error. I am new to objective-c. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make an object of your destination view controller.. For example, 
`MyViewController *myVC = segue.destinationViewController;`
Then call the setUrl method of this object. The reason is that the compiler does not know which object's setUrl method you are calling if you use 
`[[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:self.propertyToStoreTheString]`

Comment: @MeharoofNajeeb, thanks. I forgot this. But I think, casting the destinationViewController as MyViewController should work to. So you can save one line ;-)
I added this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Had a simmilar situation, this is what I did: //in class containing the webView

```
-(BOOL) validateURL: (NSString *) candidate {
    NSString *urlRegEx =@"((?:http|https)://)?(?:www\\.)?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.?[\\w\\d\\-_]+\\.\\w{2,4}(\\.\\w{2})?(.*)?"; ///(?<=/)(?:[\\w\\d\\-./_]+)?
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
  }

- (NSURL *)goToWebPage {
    NSString *fullURL;
    if(self.adressBar.text == nil){ //full text of the passed url is not nill
        return nil;
    }else if([self validateURL:self.adressBar.text]){
 #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < 80000
    if(([self.adressBar.text rangeOfString:@"http://"].location != NSNotFound) || ([self.adressBar.text rangeOfString:@"https://"].location != NSNotFound)){
#endif
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 80000
    if([self.adressBar.text containsString:@"http://"] || [self.adressBar.text containsString:@"https://"]){
#endif
    fullURL = self.adressBar.text;
    }else {
        fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",self.adressBar.text];
    }
    }else {
        NSString *new = [self.adressBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString:@"%20"];
        fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/search?q=%@",new];
    }
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [_myWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
        _myWebView.scalesPageToFit = true;
    return url;
}
```

I used this code on my very first iOS app, so I'm not very proud of it, but it did work for me.
About passing the URL, you done it ok, at least I had the same code:

```
BrowserPage * destinatinatioonViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destinatinatioonViewController.adressBar.text= [self.adressBar text];
```